Error 'Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.' when using UNION ALL
I am receiving a:

Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

error when I attempt to UNION ALL two identical queries that have been wrapped in subqueries. I am not sure what this is referring to since the queries work fine individually. Could it be the syntax?
SELECT * 
FROM (
        SELECT 
            Table1.[Owner]
        FROM
            (
            SELECT
                owneridname [Owner], 
                incidentid [Ticket Number1]
                FROM
                    incident
            ) as Table1

            LEFT JOIN

            (
                SELECT
                    MAX(DATEADD(hh,-7,svb_timestamp)) [Time Stamp],
                    svb_caseid [Ticket Number2]
                FROM
                    svb_caseupdate
                GROUP BY svb_caseid
            ) as Table2
         ON Table1.[Ticket Number1] = Table2.[Ticket Number2]
) sq1
         
UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM (
         SELECT 
            Table1.[Owner]
         FROM
            (
            SELECT
                svb_cssowner [Owner], 
                incidentid [Ticket Number1]
                FROM
                    incident
            ) as Table1

            LEFT JOIN

            (
                SELECT
                    MAX(DATEADD(hh,-7,svb_timestamp)) [Time Stamp],
                    svb_caseid [Ticket Number2]
                FROM
                    svb_caseupdate
                GROUP BY svb_caseid
            ) as Table2
         ON Table1.[Ticket Number1] = Table2.[Ticket Number2]
) sq2

I was expecting to append both tables together which should be fairly simple.

When you use UNION, the fields of the second query - which might have worked perfectly on its own - get converted into the same data type as the corresponding fields of the first, and this might not always be possible. Try converting the type of the first field of the first query in the UNION to character string (now it's apparently uniqueidentifier).

You already asked this and got the same comments

Rather than having two identical queries except for selecting a different column from incident you would be better off using something like SELECT V.[Owner], incidentid [Ticket Number1] FROM incident CROSS APPLY (VALUES(svb_cssowner), ( CAST(owneridname AS VARCHAR(36)))) V([Owner]) and then joining that

You are trying to union incident.owneridname and incident.svb_cssowner. The DBMS tells you

Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

So, one of the two columns is a uniqueidentifier column, while the other is a string column. The DBMS tries to convert the string value to a uniqueidentifier value, and this fails. What you want instead is to convert the uniqueidentifier column to a string, so as to have strings that you union.
Probably something like
(
  SELECT
    CAST(owneridname AS CHAR(36)) AS [Owner], 
    incidentid [Ticket Number1]
  FROM incident
) as Table1


This solution worked! Thank you for the explanation - this makes a lot of sense.
